# Is there a way to see processes that are actually writing to disk?

Tags: windows-7

I was alerted that my disk is full and I have no clue why. I haven't installed anything new and yesterday 10GB was still available. I just uninstalled some stuff and now, by refreshing in the explorer, and watching the partition I see the freespace decreasing. I have no idea how to figure out what is causing this or  how to stop/fix it.

I would appreciate any help on where to look.

Comment: [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor): "Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity."

Comment: See my answer for a windows builtin feature. If its your C partition that is growing, it is likely the swap file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Windows comes with a feature that allows you to see this. Its called Resource Monitor.

To access Resource Monitor, do the following:

Go to `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools` > `Resource Monitor`

From the `Overview` tab you can open the Disk section to see all disk activity, or go to the `Disk` tab to get a split view by Process and all.

Answer (score 0):

LPChip's answer is correct.  However, there are alternatives.  [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) from Microsoft's [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) will also tell you what application is writing a file.

Comment: There are many tools that can do this job, some even better than others. I've chosen for Resource Manager because everyone has it. :)